# Synchronization using python code based on an excel file to JIRA

Tags: python, excel, jira, python-jira

I am using python package 'jira' for establishing connection with the jira. I basically use the information from excel file and create tickets automatically in JIRA based on the excel information. Sometime there might be changes in the excel information for the same ticket in which case I need to run the code manually. So I would like to know if it is possible to do this automatically whenever there is a change in the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are only interested in filing new tickets. i.e. adding new rows in excel sheet.

Two options:

1. Run your code in a forever loop with sleep.
2. Have your code run by a cron.

Now, you can maintain the hash(md5 or sha256) of your file, and write the hash in some file on host machine if you are not using a database.

Your code has to read from this file, and calculate fresh hash of that excel file. If they are not same, means something has changed in your file.

Now, you also need to maintain till what row you have created the jira tickets. You can write this information also in some file.